# First digit of ternary expantion of numbers in $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let consider the interval $I=[0,1]$ and we work in base-$3$, then every $x\in I$ can be represented as $$x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k},\quad a_k\in\{0,1,2\}.$$

I must prove that if $x\in I_{0,1}=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$, then the first digit of $x$, $a_1=1$. I reasoned as follows. I observe that $$\frac{a_1}{3}\le x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{3^k}\le \frac{a_1}{3}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{2}{3^k}=\frac{a_1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\tag1$$

Then from $(1)$, we deduce that every number $x\in\left[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right]$ has as first digit of ternary exapantion $a_1=1$, then, in particular, every $x\in I_{0,1}$ ha as first digit of ternary expantion $a_1=1$.

It's correct?

Comment: Seems fine to me, except the last line "in particular, every $x \in I_{0,1}$ " looks redundant. Also,"every number in $x \in [1/3,2/3]$" is not right. Should be "every number $x \in [1/3, 2/3)$"

Comment: @DSThanks. Why do you exclude $\frac{2}{3}$? $\frac{2}{3}=0.1\overline{2}$

Comment: $(2/3)_{10} = (0.2)_{3}$

Comment: @DS $\frac{2}{3}$ admts two representation. One is the one I wrote and the other is the one you wrote.

Comment: Not if you consider [surreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number)

Comment: But you're right anyway in real analysis. Also, my point wasn't to emphasize the open or closed interval, it was to emphasize "every number **in** ..." is wrong terminology

Comment: @DS ok, thanks!

Comment: Both extremes can be written starting with or without a $1$.  However, if you pick a convention on which notation to use then probably only one of them.